# program ignores if else statments

Tags: c, if-statement

I have written a very simple code to make sure it works propperly before I implement it into a larger project of mine.
The user is presented with a list of three options and the user should pick one, in this code it displays his/her option.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    int allowed;
    printf("Pick any:\n 1. one \n 2.two \n 3.three \n");

    c = getch();

    do{
      //getch();
      if (c = '1'){
        printf("ONE");
        allowed = 1;
      } else if (c = '2'){
        printf("TWO");
        allowed = 1;
      } else if (c = '3'){
        printf("THREEEEEE");
        allowed = 1;
      }else{
        printf("Choice was invalid, do it again:");
        allowed = 0;
      }
    }while (allowed = 0);

    return 0;

}
```

However, the out put will always print: ONE, no matter what i hit on the keyboard and the debugger shows that it gets to the first allowed = 1, then skips to the end of the do while loop.

Could anybody tell me why?

Comment: To avoid overlokking the mistake your are doing I tend to put the constant on the left side of a comparsion operation; that is (`1 = c`) in your case. Try it! ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When comparing in c you have to use the double-equal operator (==). So, when you're comparing if (c = '1'), you're assigning c the value of '1' and this returns true. Change

```
if (c = '1')
```

to

```
if (c == '1')
```

Comment: Thanks! something i didn't realise and its fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change

```
if (c = '1')
```

to

```
if (c == '1')
```

This is because `c = '1'` assigns `c` to `'1'` and returns `'1'` which evaluates to true thereby triggering the `if`.